ValueError: Expected input batch_size (2) to match target batch_size (4)
Here is the code for a text classification task I am doing. The issue seems to lie here. This is a multi class problem. I have 3 labels. I tried several things. I changed the format of the labels to integers and tried looking into the loss function. I am not sure what parameter needs to be changed.
def evaluate(model, dataloader_val):
    model.eval()
    model.train(False)
    
    loss_val_total = 0
    predictions, true_vals = [], []
    
    for batch in dataloader_val:
        
        batch = tuple(b.to(device) for b in batch)
        
        inputs = {'input_ids':      batch[0],
                  'attention_mask': batch[1],
                  'labels':         batch[2],
                 }

        with torch.no_grad():        
            outputs = model(**inputs)
            
        loss = outputs[0]
        
        logits = outputs[1]
        loss_val_total += loss.item()

        probs = torch.argmax(logits, dim = 1).detach().cpu().numpy()
        label_ids = inputs['labels'].cpu().numpy()
        predictions.append(probs)
        true_vals.append(label_ids)
        
    loss_val_avg = loss_val_total/len(dataloader_val) 
    
    predictions = np.concatenate(predictions, axis=0)
    true_vals = np.concatenate(true_vals, axis=0)
    
    ### after evaluating we resume model training
    model.train(True)
    
    return loss_val_avg, predictions, true_vals

And this is the error I get
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-a095c6ad8f10> in <module>
     44                      }       
     45 
---> 46             outputs = model(**inputs)
ValueError: Expected input batch_size (2) to match target batch_size (4).


Might it also be a problem that I am using BertForSequenceClassification?

Does this happen immedietaley, or after some time? What are shapes of batch[0], batch[1] and batch[2]?

I am not sure if you are intentionally doing that, but giving labels as an input to the model with
outputs = model(**inputs)
seems to be the issue for me. You should remove labels from the dictionary inputs. Also, if your model is BertForSequenceClassification then it will not accept labels as input and it will not automatically calculate the loss function. Try changing your code into
def evaluate(model, dataloader_val):
    model.eval()
    model.train(False)

    loss_val_total = 0
    predictions, true_vals = [], []

    for batch in dataloader_val:
    
        batch = tuple(b.to(device) for b in batch)
    
        inputs = {
                    'input_ids':      batch[0],
                    'attention_mask': batch[1]
                 }
        labels = batch[2], # your labels should be given in dataloader as one-hot encoded values
                 
        with torch.no_grad():        
            outputs = model(**inputs)
        
        loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(outputs, labels)
    
        loss_val_total += loss.item()

        probs = torch.argmax(outputs, dim = 1).detach().cpu().numpy()
        label_ids = torch.argmax(labels, dim = 1).cpu().numpy()
        predictions.append(probs)
        true_vals.append(label_ids)
    
    loss_val_avg = loss_val_total/len(dataloader_val) 

    predictions = np.concatenate(predictions, axis=0)
    true_vals = np.concatenate(true_vals, axis=0)

    ### after evaluating we resume model training
    model.train(True)

return loss_val_avg, predictions, true_vals


Tried this but I get the same error

Also, I did the same modifications for the training loop and I get a different error. This one is in the training loop. TypeError: cross_entropy_loss(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not SequenceClassifierOutput

Okay, it seems from the documentation, BertForSequenceClassification does get labels as input. Can you share the shapes of batch[0], batch[1] and batch[2], also the line where you initialize the BertForSequenceClassification model.
